# depth buffer not working with GLFW

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I have the hints:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, GL_TRUE);
```

then later on I have:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
```

and when drawing I have

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

but the result clearly doesn't use the depth buffer...

I feel like

> ```
> glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, GL_TRUE);
> ```

might not be correct?

---

I am using GLFW 3, OpenGL 4.1, macOS El Capitan 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

According to the GLFW guide [1], `GLFW_DEPTH_BITS` can not be used to enable or disable depth testing, but to set the size of the depth buffer in bit.

What `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, GL_TRUE);` does is, it sets the depth buffer size to 1 bit, since `GL_TRUE` is defined as `1`. A depth buffer size of 1 bit is probably not even supported by the OpenGL implementation, which you could check using `glGetError` [2].

On Windows, you usually don't have to set the depth buffer format at all, it just works out of the box with GLFW. I remember, however, that it was neccessary to configure the framebuffer on iOS. So, just delete the line `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, GL_TRUE);` and see what happens.

[1] http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html

[2] https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetError.xml

Comment: yeah that hint was a recent addition, so deleting it still doesn't make it work sadly... I might try changing it to a different number other than 1 though

Comment: ok I changed `GL_TRUE` to `8` , `16`, `32` and then `64` and still doesn't work

Comment: The default value is `24`. If it does not work with that value, there might be some other problem.

Comment: :( ye also doesn't work with 24, might just make my own depth buffer and forget this hassle

Comment: Are you somewhere explicitely setting the format of your framebuffer's depth attachment (`GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`)?

Comment: hmm nope haven't used that anywhere

Comment: Have you already had a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379330/opengl-depth-problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160258/discussion-between-theo-walton-and-j00hi).

Comment: @j00hi: " depth buffer size of 1 bit is probably not even supported by the OpenGL implementation, which you could check using glGetError [2]." No, managing the windows/visuals/pixelfromats/framebuffer-configs is totally outside of the scope of the GL, hence you cannot use `glGetError` to detect any errors on that level.

Answer (score 0):

If the framebuffer is user-defined, ensure that a depth buffer is attached to it or else the depth test is disabled as documented [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test).

> If the current framebuffer has no depth buffer, then the depth test behaves as if it is always disabled.

Example:

```cpp
GLuint fbo, texture, depthRenderbuffer;

// Generate framebuffer and bind it
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

// Generate and bind texture
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// Add a texture
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

// Attach the texture to the framebuffer
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

// Generate and attach depth renderbuffer or else depth testing will be disabled
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
```